# What do you call the facial expression where the mouth and the eyes are wide open?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I am thinking about "in awe", but that doesn't necessarily imply that the eyes are wide open and the mouth is also wide open, so if there's no such word is there a phrase that you can use to convey the same idea? I could only come up with the phrase "their eyes and mouth were wide open" or "the expression where the eyes and the mouth were wide open", which both sounds awful.

Comment: I would call that expression "shocked ____". Depending on the emotion causing it, either "shocked amazement", "shocked disbelief", or maybe "shocked horror."

Comment: But what if the eyes are gouging out?

Comment: Eyes "popping out", or "bugged out"; "gouging" is the monstrous act of digging the eyes out of someone's face (permanently maiming him). I think "shocked amazement", "shocked disbelief", and "shocked horror" would all make your eyes bug out. Oh, yeah, ...: "agog". I think "agog" is the name of  your expression.... Well, I still think so, but the dictionary (-ies) don't seem to back me up. They say that "agog" is an emotion, not a facial expression.